# Entendiendo META VIEWPORT

Tags: html, css, viewport

No entiendo `meta name="viewport"`. Estoy usando el ejemplo que ofrece [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) y no soy capaz de entender para qué sirve, qué es lo que hace exactamente. He leído la explicación y entiendo perfectamente que dice que sirve para configurar el ancho de la página al ancho del dispositivo `width=device-width`, y el nivel de zoom cuando la página se carga por primera vez `initial-scale=1.0`, pero no consigo ver su efecto. Me explico...

Usando, como digo, el ejemplo que ofrece [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp), veo en su código, en el que está hecho con `meta name="viewport"`, que además de esta etiqueta meta le han incluido un código CSS que es el que realmente genera el efecto que se supone que hace el viewport. El código CSS es:

```
<style>
img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
</style>
```

Si nosotros comentamos la línea `max-width:100%`perdemos el efecto que se supone que realiza el viewport. Por este motivo no termino de entender para qué sirve realmente el viewport.

Comment: Si pruebas ese ejemplo en un movil verás la diferencia, o puedes probarlo en el modo dispositivo (Device Mode) en la herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome

Comment: Ya he probado en el móvil y no termino de verlo. Sigo indagando.

Answer (score 3):

Antes que nada quiero sugerirte que NO uses w3Schools, existen muchos medios donde esto se explica con mucho detalle, aunque puede que ya se hayan solucionado la mayoría de sus "problemas":

- http://www.w3fools.com/
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

La mejor fuente (al parecer) hoy por hoy es [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

---

Teniendo en cuenta que ya entiendes para que sirve el `viewport`, vamos a ir a la práctica:

Si no incluyes `width=device-width`, le estás permitiendo al navegador usar un ancho arbitrario, definido por el fabricante del navegador, en muchos casos es 980 o 1024 píxeles, aquí no hay un valor correcto o incorrecto, simplemente los creadores de los navegadores asignan un valor. A partir de ahí, los navegadores hacen un zoom automático para que los 980px (el ancho del documento) quepan en la pantalla actual (en caso que sea un dispositivo con ancho inferior a 980px).

Aquí puedes ver más información al respecto del ancho por defecto:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/
- http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2012/12/using-meta-viewport/

---

Si no incluyes `initial-scale=1`, puedes tener problemas de tamaño (zoom) de los elementos de la página al cambiar de orientación (en un dispositivo móvil), mientras al incluirlo se mantiene el zoom de los elementos en ambas orientaciones. También evita que la página cargue con un zoom (1.5, 2.0, etc.= asignado por la misma o por algún bug.

Podríamos decir que no usar este parámetro es "menos grave" que dejar de usar el anterior.

En el siguiente enlace puedes ver una demo al respecto:

- https://css-tricks.com/probably-use-initial-scale1/

---

Puedes "probar" o ver tu ancho y zoom actual (según el navegador): http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/defaults.html

Comment: Muchas gracias. Voy a revisar toda la información que me das y cuando lo tenga más claro te contestaré más detenidamente. Gracias nuevamente